# Multiple similar information event in a few seceods

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer, events

I was checking Windows Event Viewer and noticed that multiple exactly similar  information events related to my touch pad driver is recorded, all separated by just a few seconds. The event description is something like that some *policy scheme is reset from a registry A to B* (although, in fact in my case, this A and B are same registry files). Is it normal to have this resetting thing multiple times?

Here is a screen shot of my monitor. The first 14 rows are exactly the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for those events. Apparently, every time I touch the touchpad, the energy scheme changes to some sort of *activated mode* and goes back to normal (*low power usage* if you want) as I remove my finger. So those were actually due to the fact that I was using my touchpad only! As a consequence, this **is completely normal**.